# I want to find quoted string html file using python beautiful soup and replace with same text but with different style quote

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to fetch quoted string pattern which i'm able to do,
my requirement as follows:
example:  examplepattern = "Sometext", output = “Sometext”

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html_file="Helihoist.html"
HtmlFile = open(html_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
source_code = HtmlFile.read() 
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'html.parser')
pattern=re.compile(r'"(.*?)"')

texts=soup.findAll(text=pattern)
for text in texts:
    print(text.replace_with(re.sub(pattern,f'“{pattern}”',text)))
```

example output text I'm printing from beautiful soup which is not replacing with above approach [image]

text example here:

```html
<td>Activate</td>
<td>Click > <strong>"Activate"</strong> button to activate Helihoist orientation Stop.</td>
```

output:

```html
<td>Activate</td>
<td>Click > <strong>“Activate”</strong> button to activate Helihoist orientation Stop.</td>,
```

it could be any tag

can anyone let me know where it is going wrong?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: @Unmitigated quotes should be replaced, input:"text" output :  “text”, it has to be same text with different style quote.

Comment: You're not using `re.sub` correctly - it should be `re.sub(pattern,r'“\1”',text)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\1` to refer to the first capture group in the replacement string.

```py
for text in texts:
    text.replace_with(re.sub(pattern, r'“\1”', text))
print(soup) # show actual full result after replacement
```

Comment: Hi @Unmitigated,its not working, it's replacing with emojis,can you show working code as example print